# How to set default display card in HP Laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I recently bought new HP Envy 15 Notebook PC 15-k201ne. It's has two graphic cards. One is Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M. Now the thing is I want NVIDIA graphic as my default graphic adapter. As it will provide me more display quality. How can I do this as my default graphic adapter is integrated Intel(R).

Comment: You can disable graphic-on-board in BIOS.

Comment: @duDE there no such option in BIOS

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, it has Dynamic Mode switchable graphics and is controlled by the nvidia driver as to when it is needed and swapped to the nvidia chip, this is a limitation of the crappy consumer HP bios and the Nividia driver, nothing you can do as far as I know.

[HP Support Document](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02731962&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0002)

Answer (score 0):

1: Go to **Device Manager** by typing it out in the Start menu search bar.

[image: What i just said in step 1]

2: Click on Device Manager and click on the arrow next to **"Display adapters"**.

[image: What i just said in step 2]

3: Right click on your Intel graphics driver and click disable, the following box should popup.

[image: "Disabling this device will cause it to stop functioning. Do you really want to disable it?]

4: Once the Intel driver has been disabled, restart your computer and it should use your default to your NVIDIA driver.

[image: Just shutdown your PC]

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to do this, as far as I know. Yes, you can hard disable integrated graphics via the device manager, however, this will lead to windows running a software gpu, with nvidia control panel opening "There is no display connected to nvidia gpu". Unfortunatly your best bet is to stay in dynamic mode and edit what program you want used in the nvidia driver.

I was personally quite disappointed to discover this as I wished to use the NCP to force 4:3 stretched mode on my display in CS:GO, now I have to bust out a monitor, witch may be better in the end given my native display is only 60hz with an ungodly amount of g2g latency, anyways maybe HP will change their ways in the future (probably not).

Answer (score 0):

Some HP laptops have different BIOS menus. Use the relevant method below to vary the graphic card settings.

Disable Hybrid Graphics (G4 and G5)

Restart the pc and hold the Escape key. (Note: The "entering startup" menu are going to be displayed at rock bottom left of the screen)

From the Startup Menu, press the F10 key to enter the BIOS setup utility.

Click Advanced.

Select Built-In Device Options.

Select Graphics, then select Discrete Graphics.

Click Save, and, when prompted, click Save changes and exit BIOS.